# Reverse visual order of elements with full height

Tags: css-float, reverse, css

I'm trying to reverse the order of 2 elements that are full-width and one on top of the other.
I tried using floats which works if the 100% width setting wasn't important.

Here's an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/f3acee81fd6785529fd5

Is it possible to reverse those 2 blocks as if they were reversed in source order using only CSS?

**Constraints:**
I can't use Flexbox.
Heights are unknown.

Thank you.

Comment: Right, I'll edit the question to state they have unknown heights. Thanks.

Comment: It can be done with JavaScript, not CSS though. In jQuery you could do it like this: `$('.second').insertBefore('.first');`

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS solution. JS is easy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure css the only possible way would be to use the `table-footer-group`, and the `table-header-group`, since your container is a `diplay:table`.

```
.container .first
{
    display: table-footer-group;
    width:100%;
}
.container .second
{
    display: table-header-group;
    width:100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you set the .container as always `display:table`, and `width:100%`, it will work as you want.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HUFyu/2/

Comment: Whoa... super-hacky and clever. I suppose this works in IE9+.

Comment: Yes. According to w3schools, it works even in IE8, but requires !DOCTYPE. Just won't work in IE7-

Comment: Thank you. [extra chars]

Answer (score 1):

you can use display: table-header-group/table-footer-group

```
.container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .first{
    display: table-footer-group;
    width:100%;
}
.container .second{
    display: table-header-group;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, electrophanteau (cool name). I'll accept Salazar's answer because StackOverflow says it was posted first.

Comment: np, just tryin' to help ;)